# how to load specific xml layout file based on device screen size?

Tags: android, android-screen-support, xml-layout

i have tried with these instructions available on this devoloper [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

I need to load `res/layout-w1024dp-h768dp/activity_main.xml` on a device of resolution 1024x768 or else a default xml file, so i configured my AVD and my project explorer looks as follows
[image]

i have tried with all, but its not working on AVD of that spec..
can anybody please help me out...

here is manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.fm_player"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<supports-screens android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="768" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: that is the actual density of device

Comment: post the AndroidManifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can Android deal with two different resolutions in the folder name?

Have you tried using:

```
res/layout-sw768dp
```

which will take the shortest length of 768, from both the width and height?

Comment: next, obvious, question is: are you definitely using a device that is the correct size? And are you compiling against a version of Android SDK > 3.0?